# I need help finding why my computer was fried

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, fan

So, my power supply burned out, and it happened for the second time in a row. The first time it was because I was using old drivers, but later on me and the original owner changed the hard drive to the original one, eliminating the problem.

So, my house in Hemet, California has one side built in 1906, and the other in the 50's. No plug in the house has a grounded outlet, and I have a faulty Surge Protector on an ancient Cisco Power Strip. I have to use one of those adapters to take off the ground on the plug to get rid of the Ground problem, and it is basically impossible to add ground.

Next, My computer overheats a lot and you can hear the fans running at full speed all of the time. The original owner told me to get a new fan, but now he is telling me that it honestly doesn't matter. But, ill put it here for later reference.

Then, I also have a GTX 1080 in my computer, and it definitely isn't cooled enough as well. Because both fans, for the CPU and GTX are running at full speed.

And, as usual for any computer, there is tons of dust everywhere as well as dirt residue from the dust.

Please help me in this topic! It would really help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You definitely should clear the dirt and dust first. Don't know about the grounding, though.

Comment: A power supply doesn’t burn out due to drivers.  Sounds like your problem is due to the fan, heat, and dirt.  All conditions you can correct.

Comment: "_No plug in the house has a grounded outlet, and I have a faulty Surge Protector on an ancient Cisco Power Strip._" ... I'd strongly advise you to fix all of these issues...

Comment: Your error description sounds a lot like you have caught some kind of malware - like a BitCoin miner using your CPU resources or such...

Comment: Surge protectors do not work if they are not grounded. They cannot direct the surges to the ground.

Comment: @RonMaupin - That is a good observation.  Since the author is using a "faulty" surge protector, even if they were connected to ground, they would not function.

Answer (score 2):

Running your computer without proper grounding is likely the source of your power issues.  Not only is it dangerous to the electronics, it is dangerous to you.  The computer can be damaged without warning at any time from static electricity, which has no way of being discharged.  Not to mention another source of voltage coming in contact with it.  The static or extra voltage can originate from various sources, internally or externally from the computer.

Simply put: **Do not run electronics that require grounding, ungrounded.**  There is enough power running through that computer to kill a person.  You should consider hiring a licensed electrician to evaluate the wiring in your home and put in a proper grounded outlet.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 reasons a Power Supply can fry.

First, it is important to understand what a powersupply does and how it works.

A power supply unit (PSU) gets electricity from the mains and transforms this into low voltages that the system needs. Because the components in the system needs a lot of these small voltages, the PSU needs to convert them into a lot of packets. (This is not technically true, but I'm trying to write it down to an easy to understand level). Basically, this demand is called watts. This is why you get a PSU with a high wattage rating nowadays, and the stronger your graphics cards and CPU are, the more wattage you need.

All this conversion has one side effect. It generates heat. That's why your Power Supply has a fan too. In a dusty environment, if the fan gets clogged or otherwise the heat can't be removed properly, the heat inside the PSU builds up which means that the components get hotter. Like any electronics, if it gets too hot, it burns out.

But there's another problem.

Electricity can be affected by magnetic fields. A magnetic field can induce voltages or otherwise alter them. The reason why devices with high wattage uses always have a ground, is because through this ground, the magnetic field can be stabilized. If your environment is not having problems from a magnetic field, in worst case, the pc can become a little bit unstable. But in worst case, the voltages can be enough to cause interference with the magnetic field that is being used inside the PSU to transform power or even fry other components, such as your memory.

That said, add them together, and it's likely the PSU will go sooner rather than later, which is why this happened twice.

As stated in the comments, a surge protector is very much useless in your case, because all it does is protect your components from an electrical spike that happens outside of the system. Any surge protector does this by measuring the difference between the - and ground. Given that ground is not connected, when the system attempts to move power to the ground, it won't flow, and as such the surge protector will never fire.

Final note: as you can read in this answer, a PSU really does not care for software. A failure is therefor never a driver issue.